# Batch distributions between annotators and supervisors

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming

5 annotators are asked to annotate 1000 documents. (200 each)
Then, 3 of them are chosen to review the 1000 annotated documents.
How to organize the distribution so that a supervisor does not review his own annotations?

My solution is

A, B, C, D, E the annotators

A will review 200 documents from D, 133 documents from B

B will review 200 documents  from C, 133 documents from A

C will review 200 documents  from E, 67 documents from A, 67 documents  from B

I am not sure how to mathematically model this problem, so my questions are:

What is the mathematical domain of this problem in order to model the problem? (combinatorics?)

Is there a formula with a variable number of annotators, documents, supervisors, etc...?

Comment: I think the question should be polished a bit and you should explain more explicit some details (such as that each of A,... E probably annotate 200 documents and that the 3 supervisors also annotate, etc...). In general, I think that if you google "linear programming" and "constraints satisfaction problems", that might be related.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question to make it a bit clearer. If it is indeed a linear programming problem, you have answered my question!

Comment: maybe you could try to formalize what is the objective. Because formally speaking, another, much simpler solution is that A annotates everything and B reviews everything.